# How do I write a bin/script for these bash and ruby commands?

Tags: ruby, bash

I am constantly writing these commands in terminal but I don't know how to write a script for it. What can I do? These are the commands I would write in succession in both bash and irb:

```
# in bash
docker exec -it <some_container> bash
irb

# now everything below is a ruby command    
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

required_load_path = File.expand_path(".")
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(required_load_path) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(required_load_path)

Dir['config/*.rb'].each { |file| load file }

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'development'
...
```

I have a ruby project with a bin folder. What script can I write that would automate all of this? I'm currently having trouble because when I run the docker exec part... the irb part isn't run next for some reason.

Comment: look at a cli tool like slop or thor. This could then be called directly from the command line  as `ruby /script/location parameters`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to execute the ruby script on Docker, one alternative is to create a ruby file with the commands you want:

```
# rubyscript.rb
puts 'hello'
# ...
```

And call it with docker exec:

```
docker exec -it <imagename> ruby rubyscript.rb
```

However if you want to run something and stay in REPL to execute more stuff, you could for example call pry inside the script:

```
# rubyscript.rb
puts 'hello'
# ... 
require 'pry'
pry
```

This will execute your stuff and stay within pry, executed on the Docker container.